# is there a name for this series $p_{n,j}=\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2\pi)^j$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, power-series

Is there a name for this series? 
$$p_{n,j}=\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2\pi)^j$$
Mathematica 10.0 does not produce closed-form expression.

Comment: Woudn't that just be the same as $\pi^j\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n k^{2j}$?

Comment: @BenS. Thanks a lot! It is just the harmonic number. Best

Comment: @BenS. Please add an answer so that I can accept it. Otherwise it may leave as unanswered.

Comment: geometric series?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments: This is the same series as $\pi^j\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{2j}$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AlexM. The OP asked me to do this. This originally was a comment. See the comments on the question.